# Patriot Missile Software Bug (Range Gate Calculation)

Tags: algorithms, physics

Okay so I was reading about the Patriot Missile Software Bug, where to calculate the predicted range gate the missile system relied on the time keeping, however it would convert the whole/integer time number it stored (say 3600000) to 24 bit multiplying it by 1/10 (0.00011001100110011001100) to produce the time in real format in seconds, this way 'truncating' the actual time it computed before the converstion to a 'slightly smaller number' due to insufficient precision of 24 bit limitation. My question is not about the conversion or binary manipulation but rather how was the range gate calculated after taking the new calculated/truncated time into account for the purposes of establishing a 'distance/location/space' of where to look for the coming missile? Say the missile velocity is 2km/s, the time it was detected is at 100hrs.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a computer science question.

Comment: which section should I post it to?

Comment: Wait for the moderators to weigh in.

Comment: the question is not very clear to me.

Comment: I'm confused about what you are asking.  You say "to calculate the range gate the system [did such-and-such]", but then you ask "how was the range gate calculated [..]?"  Your question is embedded in a rather long sentence that I am having difficulty understanding. Can you break down your question into smaller pieces, and provide some context/motivation for why you are asking?

Comment: Are you asking how to compute where a missile will hit? You'll need physics for that, not CS.

Comment: Yes I am asking where a Patriot Missile System will point its' radar (the new range gate). And thank you I will refer the question to physics.

Comment: plz cite what you were reading. think careful/ systematic study of (famous) software defects seems ontopic in CS to me, even an important topic that is maybe understudied. admittedly it does tend to have more literature in software engineering than CS side. the basic issue with this bug is that trajectory calculations involve very precise time measurements and if the clock is not of the correct resolution or there is some glitch in the clock, the trajectory will be off. the missile is basically calculating/ predicting the future location of the fast-moving target requiring high clock accuracy.

Comment: “How could such bugs be avoided” would be computer science, but “how did this particular software calculate this particular value” is very far from computer science.

Comment: The only way I can understand the system calculated the range gate for the incoming target was first to detect a flying object at say point a then follow the same target till the point b (distance b, time b). It would then take the distance difference between b-a and truncate the time b to estimate the target's velocity. Based on this derived velocity it could then estimate the 'range gate' for final verification (if you truncate the time between two points, the flying object is determined to be faster).. So to me this seems that the target's miscalculated speed = false range gate prediction.

Comment: If anyone has got a better understanding behind the range gate calculation please share.

Answer (score 1):

there is some scientific/ engineering analysis of this defect & its background by professionals eg this turned up by the [SEERI](http://seeri.etsu.edu/) institute, Software Engr Ethics Research institute, [An analysis of the patriot missile system](http://seeri.etsu.edu/SECodeCases/ethicsC/PatriotMissile.htm) (note, some glitch with figure(s) at time of this writing). essentially the missile tracking logic is highly time dependent and relies on the clock being accurate to predict the missile location and intercept position and steering corrections. there are many other "classic" bugs in software that are related to clock logic. analysis of the failure also includes/ points to inadequate testing.

another reference cited in that article, [Roundoff error and the patriot missile](https://www.ima.umn.edu/~arnold/disasters/Patriot-dharan-skeel-siam.pdf) / Robert Skeel, SIAM News.

this particular defect is getting some attention lately as it was recently ranked in the [5 most infamous software bugs of all time](https://www.bbvaopenmind.com/en/the-5-most-infamous-software-bugs-in-history/) and of course its related to missile defense technology, a hot topic during wars.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I was reading some computer science introuctory material and simply put this partitcular software bug was mentioned in the 'social issues' subcategory of the textbook without giving too much or enough detail.. Consequently I had a keen interest to disect how the miscalculation of the incoming missile trajectory relied on the (truncated) time variable.